# Drag&Drop picture in Grails

Tags: grails, user-interface

Is it possible to implement paste picture in grails? Or drag&drop picture like in gmail for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, and this is not a Grails question as anything you do to solve this problem is client side related. The end result would just be a multipart form POST to the server anyways.

Example of how to implement on client side:

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload

http://html5demos.com/file-api

Grails end of things is identical to how you implement regular file uploading, don't see any point in showing examples for that.